# Getting a string out of QLineEdit

Tags: python-3.x, string, pyqt5, qlineedit

I am quite new to the coding and have been just learning Python 3 and PyQt5 for several days. I am now coding a little prog for my friend who has to fill in very long forms for his job. I want the prog to write huge paragraphs of text for him, with him only entering the needed data.

Everything has been running perfectly well and I had no problems, but now I am just spending hours not being able to get how to turn a QLineEdit-piece into a string type of data.

Here is an extract of my code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Fill-in-form")
window.resize(600, 600)
btnQuit = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close the window")

label_a = QtWidgets.QLabel("Enter the driver's name")
label_a_a = QtWidgets.QLabel("Name:")
lineEdit_a_a = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
str_1 = str(lineEdit_a_a) # here is the problem! the varible str_1 just wouldn't get the str-function.

set_5 = "kg, to the driver " 

main_body = (set_5+str_1) # accordingly, this doesn't make sense...


class MyClass(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        print(main_body) # ... and I don't get printed what I need. 

obj = MyClass()

btnCreateText = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Create text")
btnCreateText.clicked.connect(obj.on_clicked)

vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

vbox.addWidget(label_a)

vbox.addWidget(label_a_a)
vbox.addWidget(lineEdit_a_a)

vbox.addWidget(btnCreateText)
vbox.addWidget(btnQuit)

window.setLayout(vbox)
btnQuit.clicked.connect(app.quit)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I decided not to post the whole code as it is pretty long; however, from this code you will most probably understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `str_1 = lineEdit_a_a.text()`

Comment: Dear @ekhumoro, the suggested line unfortunately didn't work... It does clear the weird code symbols that I don't need in the output, but it doesn't add the actually needed information - the one which the user inputs to the lineEdit_a_a! Thus, I get shown "kg, to the driver" (set_5 only), whereas I need "kg, to the driver **info from the str1 **"... Maybe you could suggest any further ideas? =) I really need to get it done... Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to wait for the user to enter some text and click the button. The `MyClass` code is junk and not needed. Replace it with a normal function named  `on_clicked` and connect it directly to the button. The three lines of code that gets the user input from the line-edit and adds it to the other text should be moved inside that function.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much @ekhumoro!